# How to run a python script on app engine which scrapes data from a website and send sms to my mobile phone?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sms

I am writing a Python Script, which should do the following:

1. Runs on Google appengine, every 15 minute.
2. Logins to a website (using bs4 & mechanize)
3. Scrapes data from the update section.
4. Then send the latest update to my mobile phone, through sms. (not sure how this can be achieved)

Comment: Looks like you have a solid plan. Not sure what kind of help you're expecting to get here though. Did you develop anything? Did you run into any particualr issue?

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway.

Comment: I am looking for sms gateway API to do this job.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) (for scraping data from website) that will login automatic and write a program for automate the sms feature for updates. then set a cron job on google app engine for every 15 minutes that python script run.